# Domain Mapping to static html file on DROPBOX

Tags: url-rewriting, mapping, dns, dropbox

I recently purchased a domain name from znetindia. Now I don't have any Server Host, where I can place my Static HTML file, so I placed them in  public folder of Dropbox.

Because of this I wish to point my newly brought up domain name to a long file path provided by dropbox public URL like:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2025503/servers/Experimental%20projects/letstartup.net/index.html

And I have following options in my domain name page from where I brought it:
[image]

Comment: is nobody here, who can have a solution for above issue.

Answer (score 1):

DNS will only allow you to specify a different hostname or IP address for your domain name; you cannot use DNS to specify a different URL. (DNS is used for lookups for smtp, imap, ftp, sftp, ssh, telnet, imap, sip, dns, dhcp, irc, xmpp, nfs, cifs, etc. -- far more than just web browsing.)

Many registrars / hosting providers will run a web server on a host for you that can immediately issue an [HTTP `301` response](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html#sec6.1) to an URL of your choosing. My registrar, [Gandi](http://gandi.net), has placed these controls under a "web forwarding" heading. They will run a webserver that will respond to all requests for your domain with an appropriate HTTP redirect code to an URL of your choice.

I do not know if ZNetIndia provides a "web forwarding" option -- certainly none is visible in the screenshot you included, but that isn't a surprise, because managing DNS is different than managing web forwarding requests. If they don't provide web forwarding as an option, then you can certainly get a [super-cheap webhost](http://dreamhost.com/web-hosting/) that can either perform redirects as you wish, or provide you directly with hosting.